# Quels pronoms (toniques ou normaux) peut-on utiliser pour un COI introduit par « à » ?

Tags: pronoms, compléments

En considérant la phrase suivante :

> Tu touches à Mary.

quelles sont les formes correctes à l'impératif négatif ?

> N'y touche pas.
>
> Ne lui touche pas.
>
> Ne touche pas à lui.
>
> Ne touche pas à elle.

Comment: Dans le titre il y a **pronoms toniques**. Si l'utilisation des pronoms toniques n'est pas obligatoire il faudrait reformuler la question. [Pronoms toniques](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/14/grammaire/les-pronoms-toniques-A2/index.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. > Ne touche pas au vase.  →   N'**y** touche pas.

   **Y** : pronom personnel mis pour une chose, complément d'objet indirect de *touche*.
2. > Ne touche pas le vase.  →  Ne **le** touche pas.

   **Le** : pronom personnel mis pour une chose, complément d'objet direct de *touche*.
3. > Ne touche pas ton petit frère.  →  Ne **le** touche pas.

   **Le** : pronom personnel mis pour une personne, masculin, complément d'objet direct de *touche*.
4. > Ne touche pas Mary.  →  Ne **la** touche pas.

   **La** : pronom personnel mis pour une personne, féminin, complément d'objet direct de *touche*.
5. > Ne touche pas la tête de ton petit frère. →  Ne lui touche pas la tête.

   **Lui** pronom personnel mis pour une personne (petit frère), masculin ou féminin, complément d'objet indirect.
6. > Ne touche pas à **lui**.

   **Lui** pronom personnel tonique mis pour une personne, masculin.
7. > Ne touche pas à **elle**.

   **Elle** pronom personnel tonique mis pour une personne, féminin.

« Toucher » quelqu'un / quelque chose →  COD
« Toucher » **à**  quelqu'un /quelque chose →  COI. On emploie le pronom tonique après le verbe « toucher à » + une personne.

Seule la dernière phrase (7) correspond à ce que tu demandes : « toucher à » plus pronom tonique.

Comment: Dire que le 1 n'est pas correct me semble un peu dogmatique.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Je ne dis pas que le 1 est faux mais face à ce qui ressemble à un exercice scolaire j'ai préféré réserver y pour des choses.

Comment: Un exercice scolaire bizarre, quand même : toucher à quelqu’un n’est pas vraiment courant.

Comment: @Édouard Ah bon ? Ne touche pas à ta petite sœur tu pourrais lui faire mal !

Comment: @Édouard Je parlais d’exercices scolaires justement parce qu'il n'y a que là qu'on trouve des phrases bizarres qu'on dit rarement dans la vraie vie. Ceci n'est pas vrai que pour l'apprentissage du français, bien sûr.

Comment: @Édouard Sans parler de tous les petits garçons auxquels on a pu dire *ne touche pas aux filles*, Peut-être en voie de disparition ?

Comment: La question intéressante pour moi c'est de savoir quand utiliser *y* ou *lui* pour un COI introduit par *à*. Ici c'est clairement *y*. Personne ou objet ne change rien.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Y est-il un pronom tonique ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Il a encore modifié sa question après que j'ai répondu et au départ sa question était de remplacer par un pronom tonique. [Voir](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17443529#17443529)