# What is the effect of the repeated (redundant?) "lui" in this passage?

Tags: sens, pronoms

The following is a quote from a book I'm reading <sup>1</sup>:

> Roxane est assise au fond de la classe et regarde par la fenêtre. La prof est en train de calmer une crise en avant. Le p’tit gars est à
> terre, pis y gueule, y grouille dans tous les sens. «Calme-toi, Kevin,
> calme-toi.» La prof essaie de le retenir, ça **lui** arrive souvent **à lui**
> depuis qu’sa mère est partie.

My best guess is that the second "à lui" is added for emphasis, but I'm not sure. I'm also guessing that it is redundant, but I'm not sure.

Questions:

1. Would this sentence be grammatically correct / acceptable if the first "lui" was removed?
2. Would this sentence be grammatically correct / acceptable if the "à lui" was removed?
3. What is the effect (emotional, register, semantic etc) of the three options (eg, a) as written, b) with the first "lui" removed, c) with the "à lui" removed)?

---

<sub>1: *Je voudrais qu'on m'efface* by Anaïs Barbeau-Lavalette, about 2/3s into chapter 2</sub>

Comment: Question interessante - j'ai appris quelquechose moi-même. Il me semble que vous avez raison mais il y a aussi ceci: https://youtu.be/WGoRpdGCDJA?t=504

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The verb *arriver* here is impersonal, it only exists in the third person singular: *ça arrive*, and if an indirect object is required this indirect object goes before the verb : *ça m'arrive, ça t'arrive, ça lui arrive*, etc..

1. *La prof essaie de le retenir, ça arrive souvent depuis qu’sa mère est partie* is a perfectly correct sentence, so is the indirect object absolutely needed here? I would say yes, because with only *ça arrive souvent*  we could hesitate on what *ça* represents: *Kevin qui pique une crise*,  *la prof qui essaie de le retenir/calmer*, or both?
2. *La prof essaie de le retenir, ça lui arrive souvent depuis qu’sa mère est partie* is another perfectly correct sentence. But since *lui* is the indirect object pronoun for both masculine and feminine, as such we might hesitate as to what *lui* refers to: *Kevin* or *la prof*? Indeed, are we talking about Kevin getting in a tantrum or about the teacher trying to calm him down?
3. *La prof essaie de le retenir, ça lui arrive souvent à lui depuis qu’sa mère est partie* leaves absolutely no ambiguity whatsoever, it makes the reading more fluid, because if *ça arrive* had referred to the teacher calming Kevin down, then it would have been written *ça lui arrive souvent à elle* since after *à* the [*pronom tonique*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11787/358) is required. It is clearer and also it helps emphasizing the person of Kevin, it happens to him and no one else.
   Note that *à lui* here can only work as a redundancy, and so it would not be there if we had sentence n°1: *La prof essaie de le retenir, ça arrive souvent <strike>à lui</strike> depuis qu’sa mère est partie*. If we want to mention the indirect object only after the verb we have to be explicit and not use a pronoun:  *... ça arrive souvent **à Kevin**, depuis qu’sa mère est partie*. But in order to emphasize the person of Kevin he needs to be mentioned twice, before and after the verb, either by his name or by a pronoun.
4. So what about if the teacher had been male? Then the author would used the boy's name: *L**e** prof essaie de le retenir, ça lui arrive souvent à **Kevin** depuis qu’sa mère est partie*

Comment: I appreciate this answer because I didn't even realize that the *à lui* could be referring to Kevin! (For some reason,  I was imagining a male teacher and didn't notice that the teacher was referred to with *la*). A question, still that i'm unsure about: if you removed the first "lui" but kept "à lui", is the sentence OK? That is: *ça arrive souvent à lui depuis qu’sa mère est partie*?

Comment: @silph I've added a sentence to 3. in order to answer your question in your comment, I hope it's clear enough. I did not specify in my answer  that of course the author could have written  *ça lui arrive souvent à Kevin depuis qu’sa mère est partie*, I thought you'd make that out by yourself.  One can't expect to grasp everything at once. Your questions show that you already have a good level of French and since you obviously read a lot you will progress rapidly.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  Though my level is likely far lower than you think; this is literally my first book in french that I attempted without giving up (I gave up on Harry potter and le petit prince after an hour or two with each),  and I literally enter every page into deepl after reading the page without deepl first, and I make heavy use of a bilingual  dictionary; so I am not yet even at an intermediate level!  But occasional answers from you all help guide and motivate my learning.

Comment: @silph Just to make it clear *ça arrive souvent à lui depuis qu’sa mère est partie?* doesn't work.

Comment: @jlliagre Ah bon, tu penses  que c'est pas clair comme je l'ai dit ? Si c'est le cas je vais le reformuler. Du coup je pourrais peut-être ajouter dans la foulée, que par contre « ... ça arrive souvent à Kevin, depuis qu’sa mère est partie » serait possible.

Comment: Oui, quand j'ai lu ta réponse, je me suis dit, la question 1. n'a pas de réponse et j'ai vu  que silph faisait la même remarque en commentaire. La note que tu as ajoutée traite le cas mais d'une manière peut-être un peu trop indirecte pour que ce soit clair pour tout le monde.

Comment: @None: actually, i didn't know until know that *... ça arrive souvent **à Kevin**, depuis qu’sa mère est partie* is ok, but *ça arrive souvent **à lui** depuis qu’sa mère est partie?* is wrong! it would indeed be helpful to me (when i re-visit this question months from now) if you put that in your answer!

Comment: @jlliagre J'espère que c'est plus explicite. Tu me diras si ce n'est pas le cas.

Comment: C'est *kristallklar* !

Comment: Just to add: IMO, the semi-redundant *à lui* also adds a little tone of condescension or contempt. This problem happens to this boy specifically, he's not like the others, etc. Not much emphasis, just a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

The paragraph you mentioned is written to convey the thoughts of someone in a very, very familiar way. So this is far from written French.

With this said, the repetition of *lui* is just the way some people think and speak. They would repeat words within a sentence that is not correctly constructed in the first place.

What I am trying to say is that this is not intentional and does not carry anything beyond the fact that the narrator forgot in the second part of the sentence what they were thinking in the first one.

EDIT: that made me recall how my son was tackling a similar issue as a small kid. He would write things like *... et il allait vers la maison, et il (je parle de Marc) lui a dit (à Jean) que ...* :)

Comment: Je trouve assez insultant pour l'auteure de considérer que ce qu'elle a écrit ici est une faute d'inattention et n'était pas intentionnel.

Comment: @jlliagre: ???? je ne comprends pas - on parle du fragment d'un livre, concrètement de *Je Voudrais Qu'on M'Efface* de  An Barbeau-Lavalette (EDIT: je n'avais pas remarque que l'OP avait cité le livre aussi). Vous connaissez le contexte de cette citation? La façon dont les pensées de la narratrice sont exprimées est évidemment celle que voulait utiliser l'autrice. En fait je ne comprends même pas votre commentaire.

Comment: Cette phrase est alors ambiguë. Je ne partage cependant ni l'opinion que ce n'était pas intentionnel, ni le fait que ça n'ajoute rien à la signification.

Comment: @jlliagre: la narratrice est une enfant, elle est élevée dans un environnement pauvre et sans éducation. C'est la façon dont elle parle - et le livre reprend très bien ce language.

Comment: Loin d'une étourderie, ("not intentional") l'auteure fait preuve d'une bonne maitrise de l'écriture pour écrire une phrase qui sans cette reprise aurait été ambiguë dans le contexte de la situation. La clarté de l'écriture (ce à quoi doit tendre tout écrivain qui écrit pour être lu et dans le respect du lecteur) est indépendante du niveau de langue de ses personnages.

Comment: @None: mais bien entendu que je parle du texte et de la **narratrice dans le texte** - pas de l'auteure! Je n'ai pas une seule fois fait référence à l'auteure mais à chaque fois à la narratrice - et à l'effet attendu de cette forme précise du texte.